# WordPress - Moving code to a site-specific plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I've used a few tutorials to add some functions to the `functions.php` file which are customizing the login screen.

Here is the code for one function which changes the logo:

```
/**
 * Custom Login Logo
 */
function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        h1 a { background-image:url('. get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) .'/media/login-logo.png) !important; }
    </style>';
}

add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_logo');
```

When I create a site-specific plugin in the backend so that I can take it out of the `functions.php` file, the code does not work. I know this is because when it is in the theme's folder, it understands where I am pointing to when I point to the url of the image.

I want to know how I should be referring to the image once it is inside my own plugin folder. I've tried using the `plugins_url` function and played around with that, but can't seem to get it.

If I haven't made myself clear, I have moved the code below to a new folder inside the `plugins` folder. I have activated this plugin on the dashboard, and I am trying to get the image url to function correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the image path from your theme to your plugin folder using `plugin_dir_url()`.

Example:

```
h1 a { background-image: url(' . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'media/login-logo.png) !important; }
```

The URL returned by this function includes a trailing slash so be sure to account for that. The URL displayed will be `http://{DOMAIN.COM}/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN-NAME}/media/login-logo.png`.